# Soil interpolation in ArcGIS 3D Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, interpolation, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have borehole data with different soil classifications.

I created each soil type in to individual shapefile.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to display a 3D subsoil model in ArcScene?

Can you tell me the steps to interpolate and finally visualize it in 3d with layers?

This screenshot is of my data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very good paper on it [here](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2014/1167/pdf/ofr2014-1167_carrell-tools-and-techniques.pdf) from the Illinois State Geological Survey, which basically outlines everything you would need to do.

As part of that they developed and make use of the [Xacto Cross Section toolbar](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=54584a5e302e4014a495b8fc37fe0663). A warning though: it requires VBA, which might not be a part of your standard installation, depending on the ArcGIS version.

Comment: instead of using this vba tool any other steps in arcscene we can use?if in case anyone else come across such tutorial videos or material please share...

Comment: If your working area isn't too large, and the soil layers from your borehole samples are basically consistent across the area, a "quick and dirty" solution might be to simply create some polygons to represent them. Make one for each soil type/layer, and after adding them to ArcScene, use the offset and base height settings for the layers to order them vertically for viewing from a side profile.